# Python: run python script as subprocess and get the output

Tags: python

I have a python script calculate.py with a function in it like below

```
def mytest():
    Y_pred = {} 
    Y_pred['a'] = [1,2,3]
    Y_pred['b'] = [45,54,77]
    return Y_pred
```

Now from python console I want to run the python script using subprocess and get the return value `Y_pred' into a variable. So I want something like the pseudocode below from the terminal

```
python3
>>> import subprocess
>>> returned_val =  subprocess.call([run calculate.py here and call mytest() ])
```

In the end, I want the returned value of `mytest()` to a variable `returned_val`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do a few things.

First, in `calculate.py` call the `mytest` function, add the following at the end:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(mytest())
```

Now when you execute the `calculate.py` script (e.g. with `python3 /path/to/calculate.py`), you'll get the `mytest`'s return value as output.

Okay, now you can use `subprocess.check_output` to execute the script, and get output:

```
returned_bin =  subprocess.check_output('/usr/bin/python3 /path/to/calculate.py'.split())
```

*Replace the paths accordingly.*

The value of `returned_val` would be binary string. You need to decode it to get the respective text string:

```
returned_val = returned_bin.decode('utf-8')  # assuming utf-8
```

Now, as the returned value from `myfunc` is a `dict` and in `returned_val` is a string,
you can use `json.loads(returned_val)` to get the same `dict` representation back.

Answer (score 1):

`subprocess.check_output`

```
import subprocess
[ print(i) for i in subprocess.check_output(['ls']).split() ]
```

output, my current directory:

```
b'a.sh'
b'app'
b'db'
b'old.sh'
```